# An integral from Peskin & Schroeder's QFT (2.51)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How would you solve the following integral:
$$ \int_1^\infty dx \sqrt{x^2-1} \, e^{-itx}$$ where $t$ is a constant such that $t>0$?

Comment: I do not think this integral converges for a $t>0$.

Comment: Maybe I messed something up in the change of variables. The integral as it appears in the book is: $ \int_m^{\infty} \frac{dE}{(2\pi)^2} \sqrt{E^2-m^2} e^{-i E t} $.

Comment: You may be able to attack the integral in the limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$ with [the method of stationary phase](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~krasny/math557_chapter_4.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $x = \cosh\pars{\theta}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\root{x^{2} - 1}\expo{-\ic tx}\,\dd t
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sinh\pars{\theta}\expo{-\ic t\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\sinh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=-\,{\ic \over t}\,{\rm K}_{1}\pars{\ic t}
\end{align}
where ${\rm K}_{1}$ is a *Bessel Function*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all
$$\int e^{-bx}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\;dx$$
Cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions.

If you really want to get into this you could try:
$$\int e^{-bx}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\;dx=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{b^n}{n!}\int x^n \sqrt{x^2-a^2}dx$$
By expanding $e^{-bx}$ but I warn you this route is tedious and will give you a series (seriesly). I should also note that the last antiderrivative can be found but is not easy.